# whats is wrong with this linq query?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

i have a product table which has a Title as string.

inside my view i have

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Serach","Store"))
        {

          <input type="text" name="q" class="searchbox_textbox" />
          <input  type="submit" class="searchbox_btn" />
          }
```

and inside my controller i have

```
        public ActionResult Serach(string q)
    {
        var result = storeDB.Products
                     .Where(p => p.Title.Contains(q) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(q));


        return View(result);

    }
```

when i run the page and type a word to search for it give me this error

> The specified argument value for the function is not valid. [ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = isnull ] 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The specified argument value for the function is not valid. [ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = isnull ]

whats the problem? and what should i do if i want to show users a meesage that tell them your serach 
didn't match any product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should use some logging to find out what's actually being sent to the database - but personally I'd split the query up before it gets there:

```
public ActionResult Search(string q)
{
    var result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(q) ? storeDB.Products
                     : storeDB.Products.Where(p => p.Title.Contains(q));

    return View(result);
}
```

It's *possible* that the SQL dialect supported by SQL CE doesn't support the check for emptiness that you were using - and this gets round that problem.