# Trouble with checking for null in a SQL Compact query inside and MVC3 project

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I'm working through the SportsStore example from [Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430234040). At the beginning of chapter 8 i'm instructed to edit my ProductController class, adding the .Where line as follows:

```
    public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
    {
        ProductsListViewModel viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel
        {
            Products = repository.Products
                .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
                .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
                .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = repository.Products.Count()
            },
            CurrentCategory = category
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

When I run the code i get the following error:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The specified argument
value for the function is not valid. [ Argument # = 1,Name of
function(if known) = isnull ]
```

on the foreach line in the following code block:

```
@model SportsStore.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}

@foreach (var p in Model.Products)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("ProductSummary", p);
}
<div class="pager">
    @Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new {page = x}))
</div>
```

I've searched a good bit and found a lot of references to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188641/whats-is-wrong-with-this-linq-query) in multiple places, but changing the query to

```
.Where(p => category == null ? true : p.Category == category)
```

had no effect.

Some basic information:

- This is an MVC3 project using the Razer view engine and C#.
- All of the items in my SQL Compact 4.0 database have a category.
- Commenting out the category == null bit makes the code run just fine.
- The second version I gave above is what is in the downloadable source code from their site.

It does work without the null checking, but i'm worried that if I just move on i may run into issues later on. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix it?

Comment: u getting error on which line ?

Comment: The error happens on:

@foreach (var p in Model.Products)

Comment: I don't know anything about MVC3, but could this be a problem with null / DBNull as you mention SQL Compact Edition (just guessing...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the LINQ query is being deferred until it gets to the SQL server.   My guess is that the SQL compact server has an issue with checking `category == null`.

Try using a non-deferred LINQ method before calling the Where method.  Something like

```
Products = repository.Products.ToList()
    .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
    .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
    .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
    .Take(PageSize);
```

Comment: @Gurrgg This will cause *all* products to be loaded into memory and the filtering, ordering, and paging will all be done in memory.  If there's any large number of products this will completely cripple the application.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, but the marked answer doesn't work for me because my WHERE clause is on a related table that I do not want to return in the results.  Also, returning everything and then doing the .Where() afterwards is very inefficient.

Here's a better way:

SQL CE cannot handle parameters so, the so standard construction

```
.Where(p => p.Category == category || category == null)
```

fails because LINQ needs to use a parameter to do that value comparison in-query.  But it is perfectly valid SQL to pass something like this:

```
.Where(p => p.Category == category || true)
```

because 'true' is always...well...true.  So if you parse your variable to a bool before the LINQ statement and then pass that variable to SQL CE, you're in good shape:

```
bool bCategory = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(category)) ? true : false;

Products = repository.Products.Where(p => p.Category == category || bCategory);
```

This allows you do to all the filtering in the query before returning data, and you can use this trick on as many conditions as you want without it getting messy.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if it gives the same output, I think it should, have a look on this...

```
 Products = repository.Products
            .Where(p => p.Category == null || p.Category == category)
            .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
```

Comment: I thought about that too, but i think that the intent was to display the items that matched the given category, and if none is given to display all items. I could be wrong about that, though.