# How to do a null check in a LINQ to Entities with SQL CE 4.0

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I have a LINQ query:

```
Dim result = DataContext.Items.Select(Function(p) New With {
                                          .Category = If(p.Category IsNot Nothing, p.Category.Name, String.Empty)
                                          .Name = p.Name
                                      })
```

This works fine against a SQL Server 2005,2008,2012 DB.  When I run it against a SQL CE 4.0 DB, I get this exception:

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The specified argument
>   value for the function is not valid. [ Argument # = 3, Name of
>   function(if known) = case ]

I've isolated the problem to `String.Empty`.  If I use `""` directly, the code runs fine.  It also works if I use `.Category = String.Empty`.  Seems like a bug in how SqlCe deals with a `MemberAccessExpression` inside an `If` `MethodCallExpression`.

If I take out the `.Category` line, everything works fine.  What's the right way to do a null check in LINQ to SQL CE 4?  I've checked [Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9188716/794234), but I actually want to check the DB value, not my value.  I've also seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11873187/794234), but it would load everything into memory which would defeat the purpose of using LINQ.

I still have the exception after upgrading to the EF 6 RC (as per ErikEJ's suggestion).  Here's a stack trace:

```
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeMultiCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeMultiCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Reader>b__8()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1 executing, Action`1 executed)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in the EF provider for SQLCE, fixed in version 6  https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/287

Comment: @ErikEJ I'm on .NET 4.0 and cannot upgrade to 4.5.  Any way to get the fix? (AFAIK EF 4.3+ requires .NET 4.5).

Comment: Entity Framework 6 Works with .NET 4

Comment: I just found the document that says that.  That's **awesome**.

Comment: @ErikEJ what `SqlCeProviderServices` am I supposed to be using?  I found one in the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91` assembly (that's what the NuGet package downloaded) which inherits `System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices` instead of `System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices` and its `internal`.

Comment: You need to use the prerelease EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact package http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/6.0.0-rc1

Comment: I forgot to add the `-Pre` to the nuget download.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in currently released SQL Server Compact Entity Framework provider, and fixed in version 6 https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/287. Emtity Framework 6 is supports .NET 4.0, and the NuGet package you want is EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact

Comment: I moved to the RC and I still have the error.  Stack trace above.

Comment: I've isolated the bug, details in my question.

Comment: Interesting info, why not just use "" then?

Comment: `String.Empty` is a little more explicit that I want to pass an empty string.  In this case, they both work the same and it's good enough.  I imagine I would have the same error in more severe cases though, like `.DatePlaced = If(x.DatePlaced.HasValue, x.DatePlaced.Value, Date.Now)`.  The `Date.Now` on the end would probably crash instead of turning into `GETDATE()` in SQL.